# javascript conflict in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, conflict

Can anyone help I am getting what seems to be conflicting Javascript in a Joomla site I am making. When the following scrip is added to the site I cannot add a listing in mosets tree

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If i take this code out the listing works as it should in Mosets tree but the Slider and other items are effected on the home page

http://mybridespace.co.uk

I have tried no-conflict script but this doesn't seem to work well.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Try referring to my answer regarding jQuery importing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933 else you should contact the developer of Mosets Tree as it is a commercial extension.

Comment: I second Lodders post. The developer of the extension should really be able to help you here.  Also, you don't mention the version of Joomla you're using - which could be really helpful.  Older versions were Mootools based, but they're moving to a jquery structure in 3.0 and future.