# How to handle jQuery in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have seen many people struggle to including jQuery in their Joomla projects. I have seen this question pop-in up on SO many time. Even I have asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla?rq=1) on SO while back. 
I thought of posting this, So that it will be helpful to you people.

**How to include jQuery in Joomla ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Method 1

Best and easiest way I found is(& the method I'm using without an issue) to install this extension. jQuery Easy. It's just not a extension, it will keep you out of conflicts.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327

> This plugin is meant to help clean and resolve front and back end
>   issues when using instances of jQuery alongside the Mootools
>   libraries.

## Method 2

You can including it in your template as below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE_NAME/PATH_TO_JAVASCRIPT_FOLDER/YOUR_JQUERY.js"></script>
```

## Method 3

Using PHP you can add jQuery as below. Find more info [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_JavaScript).

```
<?php
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript('/path/to_the/js/jquery.js');
?>
```

## Method 4

This way it check whether jQuery version exists. if not add it.

```
<?php
  if(!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')){
     JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery',true);
     $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
     $document->addScript('/path/to_the/js/jquery.js');
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have a few errors on your example methods and also some of the methods in class JFactory do not exist in several versions of the platform. Example: `JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')`method get().

Comment: it does. check the documentation rather than down voting answers without checking.