# Unite Revolution Slider Conflicts With jquery in Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, slider

Whenever i add the script below in the body of my joomla template (i.e default.php), Revolution Slider stops working.

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Please advice me on how to solve this conflict since another slider on my site needs that script to run.

Comment: You don't import jQuery like that using Joomla, well you can, but it sure **isn't** a good method at all. What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Lodder. I am using Joomla 3.1 of T3 Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're using Joomla 3.1, you should import jQuery using the following which will automatically use noConflict mode too:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

For a little more information (including the best way to import it for Joomla 2.5 too), see the following answer I posted a while back:

[Importing jQuery into Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes its working, but not as it should be. I noticed the script appears in between the <head> </head> tags. How can it get embedded in the <body></body> tag instead? Please advice.

Comment: you can't insert jQuery using this method into the `<body>` tag as it automatically goes into the `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

I think that noConflict() might help you:

```
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

OR

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: I'm rather new to jquery, please help me understand exactly where to place the above code. Also, what is the "other_lib.js" and "jquery.js" you are referring to in your code. Is it supposed to be a directory path to the js files involved.