# when I migrated joomla from local to server , javascript libraries not work

Tags: javascript, joomla, localhost

I migrated joomla  from local to server.
my website in xampp server was looking good

[image]

but when I upload it to server, website has :
"bad view"...
[www.hoceyn.com](http://www.hoceyn.com)
my website appear doesn't load js libraries.

how to I fix this issue?

Comment: It would be better to add the screenshot of the live site instead of a link. Paranoid people live amongst us. It's for safety as well.

Comment: It might be due to the fact that you have multiple jQuery libraries being loaded. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Comment: @Lodder it work in local...