# Joomla 2.5 Template Configuration Error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

This is my first experiment with Joomla (2.5) and I am having trouble figuring out what is not configured correctly between the two.

I started with the template and all was good but then as I was configuring / adding content I must have changed something.

The two areas in question is the "top movies" section at the bottom and the "Latest News", Recent News tabs.

Looking at the html in developer tools I can clearly see the difference but I can't figure out what to do / change / look at in the Joomla admin.

The original template is here:

http://temp.lamplighterguild.com/

The one I eventually want to go live with is here:

http://take7.lamplighterguild.com/

I'm not sure what else to post but if you'll just educate me more on what I can provide I'll be happy to update / edit.

Thank You

---

Edit

Elin you were most helpful pointing me in the right direction. What I found was that another module I was using Code 7 Responsive Slider jquery was colliding with the templates jquery. If I disable the Code 7 slider the jquery carousel and jquery tabs are back to the original.

So now I am off to figure out how to get them to play nice...including using another slider if needed. FWIW I need the images to be href links and that was not readily available using the default slider that came with the template so I grabbed another slider.

Put your comment in some form of an answer and I will mark it for you.

Thanks again.

Comment: Can you explain why you have two separate sites? How exactly have you changed the template?  Looking with dev tools the jcarousel class clearly is pretty different in the two.

Comment: The two sites are sandboxes for me to learn..develop etc. so neither is production. The "Movies" site is the original template as it is "out of the box". The other is as I started working, changing menus, theme stylesheet etc. from the original. jcarousel is a hint though. I compare that component and see what may be different.

Comment: But you could just copy the template and work with the copy on the same site. There's no reason to have two sites just to have two templates. You can easily switch between two templates while you are working.

Comment: Wellllll sure now that I know I can do that... I will next time. :)

Comment: If you wish to use the slideshow and there are jQuery conflicts, have a look at the link below which shows the best methods to Import jQuery. You could always edit the slideshow code and use my method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933