# Why can't create tab in joomla by jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

This code create tab by jquery:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../js/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
        <script src="../../../../../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../../../js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../../../js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
        <script src="../../../../../js/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../../css/demos.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
        
    <?php
    // No direct access to this file
   // defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
    ?>
    
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            tab 1
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            tab 2
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            tab 3
        </div>
    </div>
```

If i put that code in a nomal page. It display tab ok:
[image]

But if i put that code in a page of Joomla . It can't display tab:
[image]

Why can't create tab in joomla by jquery? or How create tab in a page of Joomla?
Thanks all.

Comment: It looks like it's missing the stylesheet or some of the styles you are using are being overridden.

Comment: Check whether the paths are correct or not as this is really crazy `../../../../../`

Comment: Try opening up Firebug or the Chrome developer tools and click the "Network" tab and refresh the page. It will tell you whether anything referenced failed to load.

Comment: also check you are not loading multiple copies of jQuery and that your plugins are using jQuery in noConflict mode. JQuery and MooTools both use the $ and it can cause serious problems in a joomla site.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors? It might be possible that you're not loading the libraries correctly. Also ensure you're not loading jQuery twice as this can cause conflicts. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [$this->baseurl](http://docs.joomla.org/JURI/base) for `js and css paths` and use `jQuery` instead of `$` for `no confliction` like,

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl;?>js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<!-- other scripts -->
<script>
   jQuery(function() {
      jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Check your `page source`, are you getting the `correct urls` of `js and css', Use can use `CDN` for adding `jquery and jqery-ui`

Comment: check path . it is ok.

Comment: if i use http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js ,it can create tab. But jquery-ui-1.10.3 it still can't

Comment: If you are using `Jquery 1.9` then use `Jquery-ui-1.9` instead of `jquery-ui-1.10`

Comment: i using jqery 1.9. it put in package i download jquery-ui-1.10.3\jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: i had try the same you: tab display https://www.dropbox.com/s/0hi7dejt9fsgrer/taberror.png

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my conflict between jQuery UI tabs() and Joomla SEF adding this code to my script:

```
//Get app object
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
// Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch();
// added these to lines
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setBase("http://".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```