# Jquery Loading Twice?

Tags: jquery, templates, joomla, states

I've tried so many fixes that I'm ready to just get a new template.  When checking out at our virtuemart store, the state dropdown will not work. If I switch to the standard joomla template it does work so I'm not sure.  In Firebug Jquerify doesn't help because in either template it just says "This page already using Jquery version 1.6.2"

I've contacted the template maker and they were no help and then the membership expired.

If you add any product here and proceed to checkout you will notice that you cannot select a state from IE, Chrome or Firefox

http://www.captainwoodys.com/store

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at the answer I wrote a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Comment: jQuery is loaded indeed twice. I can see that there is a jQuery version in your template files. So your template probably make the one call. Did you check the template backend settings if there is anything to disable the jQuery load ? Otherwise, check in the template files and remove the call to jQuery.

Comment: If I disable the jquery loader in the template manager everything works fine EXCEPT the picture slider on the homepage and the menu dropdowns on the main navigation BUT the rest of the pages work with the menu and the dropdown does work on the checkout page.  It appears that this file "<script src="/templates/tx_matheno/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>"  is loaded from the template and causes a problem with virtuemart.  Is there a way to make this script only load on the homepage? or is there a away to make sure it DOESN'T load on any virtuemart pages?

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to try jQuery easy which strips out the different jQuery scripts and loads only one. Here is the link to it http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327