# some joomla modules not working with different jquery versions conflicts in my custom template, how to solve it?

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-template

i have designed joomla 3 custom template with zurb foundation framework,  i think due to jquery conflicts some modules is working with latest  
 and even light box gallery not working at all even with jquery noconflict code.

this is my custom template index.php data

```
?php /**  * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2013 Enter Infolabs - All Rights Reserved. **/
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' ); 
define( 'YOURBASEPATH', dirname(__FILE__) );

JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/vendor/jquery.js');

$rightcolgrid  = "3";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
<jdoc:include type="head" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/favicon.ico" type="image/png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bubbler+One|Maven+Pro' 

rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/foundation-icons.css" />  
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

baseurl ?>/templates/template ?>/js/jquery-noconflict.js">

```
    <!--

      [if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/css/ie.css" media="screen, projection" /><![endif]-->  

    </head>

    <body>

-------------------
----------------
-----------------

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>


    <script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/foundation.min.js"></script>    

<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
```

baseurl ?>/templates/template ?>/js/jquery-noconflict.js">

```
    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any solve the issue pls.

Comment: In your code, you're importing 2 jQuery files. You should only be importing 1. Have a look at an answer I wrote a while back on how to import jQuery with Joomla: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides ensuring you only load jQuery once (as @Lodder pointed out) you have a `noConflict()` call, that will un-assign the `$` shorthand.  This will make the

`$(document).foundation()`

fail.  You should replace it with

`jQuery(document).foundation()`

Have you looked at siegeengine's port of foundation for Joomla? It could save you some headaches;  while it has the same issue with `noConflict` and invoking foundation with the shorthand `$`, it might help.

Also, why not load the jQuery off a CDN?