# Upgrading Joomla 2.5.22 to Joomla 3.3.1 shows TypeError: jQuery(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Upgrading Joomla 2.5.22 to Joomla 3.3.1 shows the following error:

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).tooltip is not a function
jQuery('.hasTooltip').tooltip({"html": true,"container": "body"});
```

What might be the solution to eliminate this error from the site?

Comment: How is you template importing jQuery? check the index.php for your template to see if it's being imported the proper way using `JHtml`. If not, then have a look at my answer here for importing jQuery with different Joomla versions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the Gantry framework. And you know the Gantry generally includes the js and css by calling this function $gantry->displayHead();

Comment: Did you install the Joomla 3.x version of the template you're using?

Comment: You need to be sure that your page loads only one jQuery and Mootools is loaded **after** that jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your browser cache (and your Joomla cache, and your template cache). 99% of the time this issue is caused by old JS libraries being loaded (especially in case of a migration from 2.5 to 3.x).