# Colorbox does not work in Joomla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, joomla

I use this http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ colorbox.
Ive uploaded the `.css` and `jQuery .js` and inserted the code with `Source`.

```
//LOAD JOOMLA SCRIPTS FIRST
<jdoc:include type="head" />

//LINK TO JS AND CSS AND JQUERY
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonag.org.ec/colorbox/colorbox.css">
<script src="http://fonag.org.ec/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

This is how I try to invoce my colorbox.

```
//COLORBOX
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("#dato_lb").colorbox({width:"100%", innerHeight:"100%", inline:true});
})(jQuery);
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery("#fuentes").colorbox({width:"50%", innerHeight:"50%", inline:true});
})(jQuery);
})(jQuery);
```

It works offline, on my computer, just perfect. But not in Joomla.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Working with Joomla 2.5.19

Comment: Are you sure you you've imported jQuery on your site? Are you getting any errors on your browser console?

Comment: @Lodder I was wondering if it is a jQuery problem. Thats the link I use to import jQuery. <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
How would I check weather it is imported or not?

Comment: To import jQuery, read my [answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471067/importing-jquery-into-joomla/12473933#12473933). To check if it's being imported, simply open your browser console (F12) and check inbetween the `<head>` tags.

Comment: @Lodder I included your `php` script in my code (at the very beginning of it, replacing your link to the template with the link to the jQuery stored from google). Pressing F12 tells me amongst other things this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/inicio/templates/allrounder-j1.6/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>`. Means, jQuery gets loaded from the template, right?

Comment: That is correct, you need to remove that as it may cause conflicts when multiple versions are being imported. It's also an old version of jQuery

Comment: @Lodder How would I remove that? If I remove that, wouldnt that mean that it will be removed for the whole website?

Comment: Open the index.php file for your template, find the line of code that is importing jQuery, and replace it with my code. Please also update to Joomla 2.5.27 as you are currently 8 versions behind and since then, security issues have been fixed

Comment: @Lodder there seems to be no jQuery loaden in the index.php of the template. I looked it through, did not find it. Tried a few searches with `jQuery` or `Google` or `.js` but thats the only think that comes up `...//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');`

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your website that has this colorbox on please?

Comment: @Lodder sure. thanks for your help! Its here http://fonag.org.ec/inicio/material-didadico.html clicking on that lightbulp (bottom left) is supposed to open a lightbox as well as clicking on the vertical written text on the right side.

Comment: Ok, you appear to have **5** versions of jQuery being imported, some of which the URL's are incorrect. My suggestion to get round this is install [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/jquery-scripts/18327). Install it, then enable it, then let me know and I will test again ;)

Comment: @Lodder 5 Versions?! How did that happen? Qith that jQuery easy I assume I do not have to load the jQuery in my script (which I insert in the article) anymore, right?

Comment: jQuery Easy will prevent all versions of jQuery being loaded and make sure only 1 is loaded. This is only for the jQuery library though, so you will still need to load the colobox.js file

Comment: @Lodder that would have been too easy. I installed the plug in and removed the tags in my code which load the jQuery. The light still wont open...

Comment: Ok, now in your colorbox script (first line), change `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` and in the jQuery Easy plugin option, make sure you have the `no conflict` option enabled

Comment: @Lodder Sorry, but where can I enable the `noConflict mode`? Is that in the PlugIn or do I need to add a peace of code. Sorry, never worked witj `.js`, `jQuery` `Joomla` before. Got thrown into the cold water here...

Comment: It's an option in the jQuery Easy settings, under the *Advanced* section

Comment: @Lodder Alright. I saw that but was afraid to click anythgin cause it states "Expert users only" and I am definetely not one. Anyway, its set like this now http://postimg.org/image/s9hhux917/ . I added `jQuery.noConflict();` infront of my jQuery code (aswell as the `$`, as you suggested and as this site suggests http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). But still not working... Without that `jQuery.noConflict();` added it is not working neither.

Comment: Also set **Fix Document Ready** >>> **Yes**. I looked at your HTML markup on your site and the jquery libraries are still there. Are you sure you enabled the plugin?

Comment: @Lodder no, that did not the trick neither...

Comment: Sorry for the long process. Now replace all your colorbox javascript with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
 $("#dato_lb").colorbox({width:"100%", innerHeight:"100%", inline:true}); 
 $("#fuentes").colorbox({width:"50%", innerHeight:"50%", inline:true}); 
}); `

Comment: @Lodder No worries. I have to thank you that you stick with me here. Its not working though. I copied and pasted your code, tried it with and without the `jQuery.noConflict();` infront of it. I set the Fix Document Ready to Yes in the `Advanced Site options` (thats where the screen shot was taken).

Comment: Ok, I wil look into it further when I'm back home